# Using XMLHttpRequest in WebExtension API to access random domains?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is it allowed to use XMLHttpRequest (in WebExtension API) to get the contents from a random url/domain?

I did give it a try with "about:debugging" in firefox and a simple extension:

```
//url=https://www.google.com
//url=https://www.stackoverflow.com
//url=http://www.test.com
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET",url, true);
```

This works nicely, i get a bytes with the contents.

I remember, from way back in the days, that javascript can't access resources located on other domain names. Is this still the case with WebExtension API or is this less restricted?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Comment: @wOxxOm interesting read thanks! I've added "https://*/" to my permissions section in my manifest. Is "Cross-Origin" protection disabled when using the "about:debugging" in firefox, cause it seems to work fine without any permissions. Or is the "Cross-Origin" protection a Chrome only feature which isn't correctly implemented in firefox?

Comment: @OkwanTegls The ability to perform cross-origin requests after requesting permissions is a feature, not a bug. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions